# The Class-Path manifest attribute in [path] referenced one or more files that do not exist

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am having a problem with Java 11/Spring Boot 2.1 migration where the project compiles but when run returns only:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:5754', transport: 'socket'
The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\{user}\.m2\repository\xalan\serializer\2.7.2\serializer-2.7.2.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: 
file:/C:/Users/{user}/.m2/repository/xalan/serializer/2.7.2/xml-apis.jar
The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\{user}\.m2\repository\xalan\xalan\2.7.2\xalan-2.7.2.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: 
file:/C:/Users/{user}/.m2/repository/xalan/xalan/2.7.2/xercesImpl.jar,file:/C:/Users/{user}/.m2/repository/xalan/xalan/2.7.2/xml-apis.jar,file:/C:/Users/{user}/.m2/repository/xalan/xalan/2.7.2/serializer.jar
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:5754', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have tried updating maven versions, maven compiler version, etc.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Do you want to fix it, or just suppress the messages?

Comment: @VGR is it a warning only and not an error? I assumed it was preventing the process from running since there is an exit immediately after

Comment: Those messages, by themselves, are only warnings, but, as with all warnings in Java, they are worth paying attention to.  They are telling you that serializer-2.7.2.jar and xalan-2.7.2.jar were expecting to find other .jar files on which they depend, in the same directory, but Maven has not assembled them into a single directory when the program is run.  If they are placed in the classpath by other means, your program is probably returning prematurely for other reasons.

Comment: I just double-checked the paths listed and the files are not there. Since this is my first time working with this particular project (I was tasked with upgrading it to Java 11 as a sort of intro to the project), might this be a missing dependency I need to download manually to add?

Comment: If the dependency were not in the classpath at all, I would expect your program to throw a NoClassDefFoundError.  I think it’s more likely that your program needs to be debugged, to determine why it’s exiting.

Comment: `they are placed in the classpath by other means` - they're probably in the application jar under `BOOT_INF/libs`, loaded by Spring Boot.

Comment: @8t12c7081 I'm also trying to upgrade to Spring Boot 2 and the application is terminating prematurely with no logs at all. Were you able to fix it?

Comment: @mohitmayank there is probably another earlier issue causing your application to exit - look into what the application is doing before it gets to this point

Comment: @8t12c7081 yeah, there was a dependency which was outdated. No idea why it was not printing any logs but just exiting.

Comment: @mohitmayank which dependency was that ? i'm having the same issue

Comment: @JoãoVieira you'll have to revisit each of your dependencies one by one. for me it was a dependency which is specific to the company that I work in.
word of advice - update each of the deps to their highest version (compatible with the Spring Boot version you're upgrading to)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this question continues to get traffic, I will post a summary of the answers and comments -

The messages described in the title are warnings, not errors, and should not be causing your app to crash.

If your app is crashing, check for errors earlier in the logs which would cause it to exit.

In cases where no error output was available, several people reported the issue was caused by an outdated dependency which needed to be updated as part of their Spring/Spring Boot/Java upgrade.

Answer (score 10):

Please check do you have "spring-boot-devtools dependency" in pom.xml then remove it and try again.

Note that this simply removes the error log.

Comment: This simply remove the error log. My application was not working anyway. I solved adding the missing dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem after changing my `logback-spring.xml` file.

The application wouldn't start anymore and I could only see some INFO messages like those you described but that wasn't the actual cause of the problem.

The application was failing after that point but couldn't log any erros messages exactly because of a issue in my `logback-spring.xml`.

So if you don't see any other error messages, try to double check that your logging mechanism is configured correctly.

Comment: This solved my issue.. I was trying to migrate to logback-spring.xml..
I delete my whole .m2 folder for this & couldn't get anywhere..
Thanks

Comment: Thanks, was exactly my problem (had a merge conflict in logback-spring.xml which i didn't see at first)

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I have got a similar error when I add a dependency to the `spring-boot-devtools`.

For the fast diagnostic you can try to disable (comment out) this dependency

Answer (score 2):

In my case the associated failure was due to other silent error (while those notifications were the only output in the log, that's why I have checked them and there were no log output associated with the actual error).

I had the wrong `application.yml` structure like this:

```
logging:
  level:
    root: ${LOG_LEVEL:info}
    ru.pflb.foundation.config.RequestResponseLoggingFilter: ${LOG_LEVEL_HTTP:trace}
    org    #<-- that caused the problem
    org:
      apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: ERROR
      hibernate: WARN
```

Answer (score 2):

I removed devtools dependency as well as spring web from pom file and it worked for me, it looks like its devtools dependency which was causing issues with different version of my oracle jar file

Answer (score 1):

Add `-Xlint:-path` [option](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) to `maven-compiler-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>-Xlint:-path</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: This did not resolve. I'm using compiler version 3.8.0 (but did try 3.7 as well), does this make any difference?

Comment: These are runtime warnings, not compile time.

Answer (score 1):

vm options -Dspring.profiles.active={profileName}

Comment: For me i was getting this error at the start of running app, where the build creates two identical jar files for jaxb-impl-2.3.0. once i set the environment to dev the app started.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. After a format correction in the configuration file the app started.

Comment: Hi Yash. Welcome to stackoverflow. Please format the code and edit the answer to clarify the issue.