# The Class-Path manifest attribute in file.jar

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I run my Spring-boot application and I get this message in console.

```
The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\maven\xalan\serializer\2.7.1\serializer-2.7.1.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/maven/xalan/serializer/2.7.1/xml-apis.jar
The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\maven\xalan\xalan\2.7.1\xalan-2.7.1.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/maven/xalan/xalan/2.7.1/xercesImpl.jar,file:/C:/maven/xalan/xalan/2.7.1/xml-apis.jar,file:/C:/maven/xalan/xalan/2.7.1/serializer.jar
```

How can I fix it because I can't run my application

ps. I don't import xalan dependency in my pom.xml

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The Class-Path manifest attribute in \[path\] referenced one or more files that do not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53565534/the-class-path-manifest-attribute-in-path-referenced-one-or-more-files-that-do)